# LaTeX custom section counter

Tags: sectioning, counters

Is it possible to recreate this numbering format in LaTeX?:

```
01. Text
    0101. Text
        01. Text
            01. Text
                - Text
                - Text
            02. Text
                - Text
        02. Text
    0102. Text
        01. Text
```

I cannot figure out how to double digit the 1st, 3rd, 4th layer. Nor how to get the second layer to be 4 digits with the 01 "prefix".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I recommend to read something about the sense of typographie first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why you hate your readers so much:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\two@digits\c@section.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\two@digits\c@section\two@digits\c@subsection.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\two@digits\c@subsubsection.}
\renewcommand*{\theparagraph}{\two@digits\c@paragraph.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubparagraph}{{}-{}}

\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.5em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3em}{2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{4.5em}{2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{6.5em}{1em}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Text}
\subsection{Text}
\subsubsection{Text}
\paragraph{Text}
\paragraph{Text}
\subparagraph{Text}
\subparagraph{Text}
\subsubsection{Text}
\subparagraph{Text}
\subsection{Text}
\subsubsection{Text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for "I don't know why you hate your readers so much".

Comment: @Mico I expected that to bring most upvotes `:-)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I know that this is horrible, but I have to "archive" an old document for my final exam...

Comment: Is there a way to add the paragraph into the tableofcontents?

Comment: @Mico What I meant was the subtext on layer 5. The list of dashed Text. They are also supposed to be sort of headings in the contents.

Comment: I add up my vote for the quote too ;) And also for the clever (although natural) solution.

Comment: @GhostJumper - You could create a special itemize-like environment via `\usepackage{enumitem} \newlist{spitemize}{itemize}{1} \setlist[spitemize,1]{label=\textendash,left=0pt}` and then run `\begin{spitemize} \item Text \item Text \end{spitemize}` in the body of the document (below `\paragraph`-level sectioning headers).

Comment: @GhostJumper See edit.